# Calculate difference in encoding WITHOUT actually writing to a file?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I have some text, that will be written to 2 files using UTF-8 and 1252 encoding.

Observation when comparing these 2 files:

- most text characters will remain the same.
- some UTF-8 characters that don't exist in 1252 will be represented as "?" in the 1252 file version.
- some characters will be converted somehow: e.g. a "Ф" or "σ" (Greek phi and sigma) will be converted to a "F" or "s" (which makes sense).

**Question: Can I calculate which character in the UTF8 file will be represented by what character in the 1252 file without actually writing the files?**

Or to put it another way: Is there more efficient code than this to find out the differences without writing to a text file?

```
File.WriteAllText("tmp-utf8.txt", text, Encoding.UTF8);
File.WriteAllText("tmp-cp1252.txt", text, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

string textUtf8 = File.ReadAllText("tmp-utf8.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
string text1252 = File.ReadAllText("tmp-cp1252.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

if (textUtf8 != text1252)
{
    ... do something
}
```

Finally I want to print out something like this:

```
"a"->"a"
"b"->"b"
"Ф"->"F"
"σ"->"s"
"ξ"->"?"
"ψ"->"?"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Encoding.GetBytes` to get the exact byte representation, and `SequenceEqual` to compare.

```
var bytesUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
var bytes1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(text);
if (!bytesUtf8.AsSpan().SequenceEqual(bytes1252))
{
    // do something
}
```

To find the exact index of differences is difficult, because UTF-8 uses multi-byte sequences in some cases.

Maybe something like

```
Span<byte> bufferUtf8 = stackalloc byte[4];
Span<byte> buffer1252 = stackalloc byte[4];

for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (!Encoding.UTF8.TryGetBytes(text.AsSpan().Slice(i, 1), bufferUtf8, out var length)
        || !Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).TryGetBytes(text.AsSpan().Slice(i, 1), buffer1252, out length)
        || !bufferUtf8.SequenceEquals(buffer1252)
    )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Index {i} does not match: 0x{Convert.ToHexString(bufferUtf8)} -> 0x{Convert.ToHexString(buffer1252)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds cool.
How can I find the differences per character?
eg. print out something like this: "a"->"a"; "b"->"b"; "Ф"->"F"; "σ"->"s"; "ξ"->"?"; "ψ"->"?"

Comment: It is possible to create a Best-Fit Fallback handler for the Encoding object, but .NET does not provide any.

Comment: "The differences you are seeing are mainly because you are viewing it in the wrong encoding." - no. if the file is written with 1252 encoding, the differences are physically in the file. Then it's not an encoding issue anymore. There is no way to get the "Ф", "σ" and friends back anymore.

Comment: Does `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` actually use fallbacks? Could maybe check the `EncoderFallback.Fallback` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoderfallbackbuffer.fallback?view=net-8.0

Comment: Note that C# strings are UTF-16 in memory, but you are processing only individual `char`s at a time, which will not work for Unicode characters that require 2 UTF-16 `char`s.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you mean the second code block? It's not using `char` there as the source, just bare bytes converted to UTF8 and from there into `char`. It's still an issue, because of the multi-byte UTF8 problem, but at least it will find differences even if the output is not accurate.